# Lines have disappeared from flextables

Tags: r, flextable

Looking at the `flextable` documentation [here](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/format.html) for `flextable_0.5.0`, there should be lines on my flextable, but I don't get any.

## Code:

```
myft <- flextable(head(iris))
myft
```

## Output:

[image]

## Expected Output:

[image]

I should be able to add lines if I want them using this code:

```
myft <- flextable(head(iris)) %>% 
  border_outer(border = fp_border(color="black", width = 1))
myft
```

But no borders appear. I assume this is a bug? Or have the commands changed but the documentation not been updated?

In the mean time, is there a way to roll back to the previous version?

## Edit:

Just re-isntalled version `0.4.6` and `0.4.5` and I'm having the same issue so not sure what's going on. I'm using R version `3.5.2`. I wasn't having this issue yesterday before I upgraded to `0.5.0`.

## Edit 2:

The latest update (`0.5.1`) has resolved the issue :) Thanks @DavidGohel

Comment: I'm getting the same issue since the update :( don't know what to do

Comment: Are you using the Windows Rstudio viewer? If you look at the documentation https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/format.html (produced with flextable), can you see the lines?

Comment: Yep I can see lines there, but it was all working yesterday and the only thing I've updated is the flextable package :( should I re-install Rstudio or something?

Comment: I pushed a fix on github. It should be ok now. Can you try with the github version?

Comment: Unfortunately still no lines appear and I can't seem to add colour-related formatting :(

Comment: @DavidGohel is there any update on this? It's really messed up all my report generation scripts :( the latest github release version didn't fix the issue for me unfortunately

Comment: @RAB then please fill an issue on github with a reproducible example (I was planning to submit the new version today).

Comment: It's fixed!! you're a legend! Thank you so much

Comment: Cool. The package is on cran now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is now resolved in version 0.5.1+ of the flextable package.